# What is the relationship between NSPersistentStoreCoordinator and NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

When do we use single and multiple - NSManagedObjectContext and NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? What will be the relation between the both in each case?